# Outlook 2013, New Mail Desktop Alert Goes Away After 5 Seconds

Tags: email, windows-registry, notifications, microsoft-outlook-2013

When I receive a new email, the desktop notification pops up and then fade away after 5 seconds. I found how to fix it through changing registry for outlook 2010 and older versions but it does not work with outlook 2013. Does anybody know how to fix it? I need the notification to stay for a desired time.

Answer (score 2):

Which OS do you use? On Win7 Outlook displays its old **New Mail Desktop Alert** at the bottom right corner of the screen by default:

[image]

You can customise this by going to `Options / Mail / Message arrival / Desktop Alert Settings`:

[image]

On Win8 though Outlook switches to using popup "toast" notifications at the top right corner of the screen by default:

[image]

You can customise these by going to `Charms bar / PC Settings / Ease of Access`:

[image]

Comment: @AliJamali: You're welcome! Since you're new here, don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.