# Extend Email Notification Longer Than 30 seconds

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013, alert

Is there a way to make the desktop email notification for Outlook 2013 in Windows 7 stay on longer than 30 seconds? In previous versions the registry could be changed to make it stay on for days. This doesn't work on 2013/WIN 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the popup appearance time in the settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that user Jess Stone's answer does not directly apply to Windows 8, accordant with [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/desktop-alert-options-are-not-displayed-in-outlook/05368d64-ad9d-4a6d-8bcf-23a900552fdf):

> As per the issue description you are unable to view the desktop alert options in the desktop alert window on Windows 8 operating system.
>
> If Outlook 2013 is running on Windows 8 the mail alert becomes a standard Windows 8 notification. This is by design. The Delete, Flag and other options are gone, possibly because such things aren’t supported in Windows 8 notifications.

If you're on Windows 8 or 8.1, then as per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/583062/269574), you must select the notification time with [Ease of Centre, which this article explains pictorially with helpful screenshots](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/14512-notifications-change-stay-open-time-windows-8-a.html).