# Display email desktop alert at bottom right corner in OL2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I just switched to Office 2013 and now the email desktop alerts pop-up on the top-right corner.

Is there any way to make it popup at the good ol' bottom-right corner? (I don't see an option to do it via Outlook's settings.)

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?  Regardless: the options in Outlook 2013 for handling the "Desktop Alerts" (what that Popup is called) are located under File -> Options -> Mail -> (Scroll down to) Message Arrival section.  Perhaps check there?

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/583041/outlook-2013-new-mail-desktop-alert-goes-away-after-5-seconds?rq=1

Comment: I'm running Windows 8.1 (not that it matters IMO). I already saw the link you attached, but in OL2013 there's just a "Display a Desktop Alert" checkbox...It's not a desktop alert - it's a tablet alert. Ever since Windows 8 they're systematically butchering the Desktop concept...

Comment: I think what you're running into (and it's probably not changeable) is that the notification system in Windows 8+ is compeltely different than previous versions.  OL2013 uses this new Notification system if it's available.  Short version: I think yer stuck, as I don't think there's a way to modify the location (etc) of the Notifications ([related link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/how-to-change-the-notification-size-and-position/5d58cefe-d364-4c8f-a9a3-dffb8a8a2bcc))

Comment: As a possible workaround, apparently Office 2010 on Windows 8 behaves the old way (uses it's own Desktop Alert system).

Comment: Up until 6 hours ago, I used to have OL2010 on my Win8 and it was running just fine. I'll try to find a Win7/OL2013 machine and see where the notification window pops up.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I was similarly baffled by this problem, until I I saw your comments that it is different in Windows 8 (and 10). So I edited my shortcut to run Outlook in Windows 7 compatibility mode. Now my notifications are back in the old style I liked. I especially missed the option to delete a message directly from the pop-up. Yay it is back!